# Dropwizard file upload

Tags: dropwizard

I have to upload a file from my site yet cnt seem to get it working with drop wizard.

Here is the form from my site.

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="UploadFile">
     <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="file"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
   </form>
```

How would I go about on the backend to receive the file?

The solution was

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {


    String filePath = uploadLocation + newFileName;
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);
    String output = "File can be downloaded from the following location : " + filePath;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String serverLocation) {
    try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new      File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can answer your own question you know? In fact you should answer your own question and not put the answer in the question

Comment: Why are you assigning to outputStream twice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do the saving to the server in lesser number of lines using nio

```
java.nio.file.Path outputPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(<upload-folder-on-server>, fileName);
Files.copy(fileInputStream, outputPath);
```

Also, if you're using 0.7.0-rc2, you will need this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
<version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After Dropwizard 0.8.0 dependency is: org.glassfish.jersey.media, artifactId: jersey-media-multipart

Answer (score 13):

With Dropwizard 0.9.2 you have to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

as well as register the multipart feature:

```
    environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Comment: I am using the same version of dropwizard as you mentioned and this approach gives me 400 bad request error. The parameters are just the same as what is stated in the question.

Comment: I forgot to register the multipart feature class! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Ensure that you add dropwizard-forms dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Your resource seems good, Anyhow I've uploaded an example project for uploading files with Dropwizard - https://github.com/juanpabloprado/dw-multipart

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/Users/Juan/Pictures/uploads/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.ok(output).build();
}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws IOException {
    int read;
    final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```