# dropwizard multipart formdata utf-8

Tags: utf-8, multipartform-data, dropwizard

I implement my server using dropwizard and for uploading my files, I use multipart formdata using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525666/dropwizard-file-upload).

but when I use files with utf-8 character set, my filename from FormDataContentDisposition object, is crashed.

code:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA + ";charset=utf-8"})
public void fileUploaded(@AuthRequired User admin,
                        @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream inputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {

    System.out.println(contentDispositionHeader.getFileName());

}
```

Comment: With using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data) I solve my problem but I can't correct the file name when it consumes with jersey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Must Change

```
System.out.println(contentDispositionHeader.getFileName());
```

To

```
System.out.println(new String (contentDispositionHeader.getFileName().getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8"););
```

Comment: See also "RESOLVED" jersey bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3032